# I want to initialize the state. ( RiverPod : StateNotifier )

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I want to initialize the state of super.

Error : The operator '<' isn't defined for the type 'Type'.

```
super(state ?? List<UserModel> [])
```

Provider

```
  final userProvider = StateNotifierProvider<UserNotifier>((ref) {
      return UserNotifier();
    });
```

StateNotifier

```
class UserNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<UserModel>> {
  UserNotifier([List<UserModel>? state])
      : super(state ?? List<UserModel> []) { // << Error 
    fatchData(); // It's same as initState();
  }
  String collection = "Users";


  Future<List<UserModel>> fatchData() async =>
      firebaseFirestore.collection(collection).get().then((result) {
        final List<UserModel> users = [];
        for (final DocumentSnapshot user in result.docs) {
          users.add(UserModel.fromSnapshot(user));
        }
        return users;
      });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List can be created by using `<int>[]` or using the constructor `List<int>()`, `List<int>[]` is not a valid format